# How long did David live?

Tags: history, david, chronology, 1-kings

From my general knowledge, I know that David lived 70 years.  Can be this be demonstrated with the Bible?

In **1 Kings 2:10, 11** we find how long he reigned over Israel:

> So David slept with his fathers, and was buried in the city of David.
>
> And the days that David reigned over Israel were **forty years**: seven years reigned he in Hebron, and thirty and three years reigned he in Jerusalem.

So, how long did David live?

Comment: Excellent question. Also on-topic at [Judaism.SE](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/). There might be an old Jewish tradition that is extra-biblical.

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks! I didn't know about this site until today and I find it as a good Bible learning resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

70 years

> David was thirty years old when he became king, and he reigned forty years. 
>   [2 Samuel 5:4](http://bible.com/111/2sa.5.4.niv)

Comment: Because of the slightly weird Israelite way of counting years, where first and last year are always counted, he might have been 69. But that's a nitpick.